# ClassNotFoundException FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jetty, freemarker

I have a big web application that uses FreeMarker. When I recently updated to Spring 3.2.4 and ran the web app via jetty or tomcat I get the following exception:         java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:     org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory.

I know that Spring-webmvc has the FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory class in it so I have the dependency included in my POM. I do not know why I´m getting the exception. I have included my POM and my spring servlet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>WhiteSwan-Web</artifactId>
<groupId>com.millad.whiteswan.web</groupId>
<version>1.5</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.12.v20130726</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
 <org.springframework.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <joda.time.version>2.2</joda.time.version>
    <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.20</freemarker.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.0-beta8</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.0-beta8</version>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.foursquare</groupId>
        <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>${mockito.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
        <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- File upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WEB APP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>20041228.180559</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2_beta1</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>${joda.time.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

My Servlet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <task:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.whiteswan.*" />

    <bean id="freemarkerConfig" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurer">
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value ="/WEB-INF/freemarker/"/>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="2000097152"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
        <property name="cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="prefix" value=""/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".ftl"/>
        <property name="exposeSpringMacroHelpers" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had to add the spring-context-support JAR to my project for it to work. Here's the Maven pom.xml entry:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't know how you figured this out, but thanks for posting it. +1

Comment: Wish it worked for me.  Changed a single line of code in a years old project, and now it won't run.  Even reverting that change won't get it to run now.